# Changing default port (i.e. 5037) on which adb server runs

Tags: android, default, port, adb

I am a budding android developer and if there is no easy way of configuring the adb server to run on another port then *the inflexibility of the tools* will force me to quit android app development.

A web search did not return any solutions.

I also searched for '5037' in all files in android sdk directory but did not find a setting there.

Comment: This is annoying. I run into it when starting multiple eclipse instances (different workspaces).  Since both have the android plugin, they conflict with each other and cause strange behavior - ex, one process shows up in one eclipse's ddms device view and one process (on same emulator) shows up in the other eclipse's ddms devices view.

Comment: You might want to reformulate your "question" to that it indeed contains a question. And take out the profanities ;-) We understand that you're frustrated, but don't complain to us, we didn't program adb.

Comment: `googled for 5 mins` Oh my god, 5 whole minutes?!?!

Comment: What is this.. `king quitting android app development` are you kind of joking out here.?

Comment: I can see why people reacted negatively to the original statement of the question, but **it's actually a quite important question, and has answers of ongoing value**.  Tools with hardcoded assumptions are quite problematic when they collide with others making the same assumption, so it's good to know that there are ways to configure this.

Comment: If adb service runs at port 5037 then why does it locate devices in the range 5555 to 5585 ? Can anyone please explain me

Answer (score 47):

Use the environment variable ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_PORT to select the port.

The following works under bash:

```
$ export ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_PORT=12345 
$ adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 12345 *
* daemon started successfully *
$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
TA2070M5O6  device
$ ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_PORT=6789 adb devices
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 6789 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached
```

In another terminal I ran:

```
$ ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_PORT=6789 emulator ...
```

Back to original terminal:

```
$ ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_PORT=6789 adb devices
List of devices attached 
emulator-5554   device
$ adb devices # ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_PORT was exported as 12345
List of devices attached 
TA2070M5O6  device
```

I found this via the Jenkins [Android Emulator Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Android+Emulator+Plugin) as I noticed it was running adb on a different port.

Comment: Is there a way to attach a specific device to a particular adb server ?

Comment: you may have to run `sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb` from terminal before

Comment: @tonygil        Is there a way to do this?  You just supplied the tools, how do you actually specify a device to a particular server?

Comment: @ALM my apologies for taking so long.  I havent used ADB in a while, but this was a local wifi connection to debug my code (in Eclipse IDE on ubuntu box) on an android smartphone/tablet.

Comment: @JakubCzaplicki yes - make sure to have `ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_PORT` set to the same port when running the emulator. For me this seems to work unless the adb server is started after the emulator is already running...

Answer (score 32):

With the latest adb version,

Use option -P (Note: Caps P)to start adb server in a specific port.

For Example, Try

> $adb -P 5038 start-server

It will list the devices attached to this specific adb server. If the adb server is not running then it will start a new adb server with the given port number.

Hope it helps someone reading this post.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

In Windows, go to Environment Variables – Add a new one called `ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_PORT`
and set it to whatever you want, I've set to 5038.

Should look like this:

[image]

Solved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

There is another variable that supports this for connecting to a different machine's adb:

```
ADB_SERVER_SOCKET=tcp:some.other.host:1234 adb devices
```

To use it, you need to start adb on the other host with -a and probably background it too:

```
( adb -a -P 1234 nodaemon server & ) &
```

Comment: to move the adb server process to background, just omit the `nodaemon` option, no need to use `&`