# Android Adb error

Tags: android, android-emulator

Please guide me about this error

```
2011-05-02 18:37:20 - SimpleOptionMenu] The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
[2011-05-02 18:37:20 - SimpleOptionMenu] You must restart adb and Eclipse.
[2011-05-02 18:37:20 - SimpleOptionMenu] Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'F:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.
```

It was working fine and now i am getting this error . I have restarted eclipse but nothing happed . Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had this error from time to time too, and restarting Eclipse has fixed it.  My best guess is that you had the misfortune of getting the error twice in a row.  Try restarting again and see if it goes away.

Writing this post has had the unfortunate effect of making me realize that the Android SDK bears a striking resemblance to Windows.

Comment: yeah u rite but for my case restarting of system  worked instead of eclipse without knowing any major reason . Thanks for support

Answer (score 4):

When I faced with this problem, resetting adb is usually the solution.

If this not solves, unplugging-replugging the device works. I never have had to restart Eclipse.

By the way, **Reset adb** option can be found in **DDMS**(Dalvik Debug Monitor Server)'s **Devices** tab.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the reason but restating up my system worked for me :) !!!

Answer (score 0):

> I just posted the response below here:
>   [adb kill-server not responding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790421/adb-kill-server-not-responding/14421633).
>   I am duplicating it here too as Google considers this thread as one of
>   the top hits.

If zombie `adb` process is not the issue i.e. there's no `adb.exe` in the task-manager list, the problem is usually `adb` ports e.g. 5555, 5554, 5037 etc., being taken by other applications.

**Solutions:**

1. **`On all Windows`**: find the process taking one of those ports using `netstat -bn` and kill it from task-manager `Ctrl+Shift+Esc` is the shortcut.
2. **`On Windows 7 and 8`**: there's this new tool called [`Resource Monitor`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Monitor). It'll also allow you to find out the blocked port and blocking process under the network tab.
3. **`On Linux`**: the similar is done with `netstat -pn`. Feel free to use your `grep` foo as needed and kill the blocking process with `kill` or `pkill`.
4. **`Change Default ADB Port`**: Apparently default ADB port can be changed as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836571/changing-default-port-i-e-5037-on-which-adb-server-runs) by setting up an environmental variable before launching ADB. Give it shot. It'll allow more flexibility if you don't want to kill the blocking processes.