# Adb kill-server not responding?

Tags: android, adb

In ADB, I am facing an error when I am trying to print the version with

```
padmakumar@padmakumar-desktop:~$ adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.29
```

but its showing below error

```
padmakumar@padmakumar-desktop:~$ adb devices
error: protocol fault (no status)
```

**NOTE:** `adb kill-server` is not working i.e it's not responding.

and in my Eclipse console I am getting this error:

```
Android Launch!
[2012-01-09 20:31:28 - Shopping List] The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
[2012-01-09 20:31:28 - Shopping List] You must restart adb and Eclipse.
[2012-01-09 20:31:28 - Shopping List] Please ensure that adb is correctly located at '/home/padmakumar/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb' and can be executed.
```

Comment: This question is similar as of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072706/the-connection-to-adb-is-down-and-a-severe-error-has-occured

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I also came across the same error when I was trying to install one app in emulator. You need not restart PC to overcome this. Just kill the server. if 'adb kill-server' is also not working, kill the process (adb.exe) through task manager. There you go!!

Comment: restarting ur PC is a bad option.

Comment: What is adb restarts again ? Then restart solves problem

Comment: after investigating for a long time, finally i found out that adb daemon keep restarting. and it is because my chrome have enabled android debugger. In chrome address bar, open: chrome://inspect#devices, then uncheck "Discover usb devices"

Answer (score 7):

If zombie `adb` process is not the issue i.e. there's no `adb.exe` in the task-manager list, the problem is usually `adb` ports e.g. 5555, 5554, 5037 etc., being taken by other applications.

**Solutions:**

1. **`On all Windows`**: find the process taking one of those ports using `netstat -bn` and kill it from task-manager `Ctrl+Shift+Esc` is the shortcut.
2. **`On Windows 7 and 8`**: there's this new tool called [`Resource Monitor`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Monitor). It'll also allow you to find out the blocked port and blocking process under the network tab.
3. **`On Linux`**: the similar is done with `netstat -pn`. Feel free to use your `grep` foo as needed and kill the blocking process with `kill` or `pkill`.
4. **`Change Default ADB Port`**: Apparently default ADB port can be changed as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836571/changing-default-port-i-e-5037-on-which-adb-server-runs) by setting up an environmental variable before launching ADB. Give it shot. It'll allow more flexibility if you don't want to kill the blocking processes.

Comment: android studio adb wifi plugin that I installed was using the port, thus making the  adb kill-server non responsive, exit android studio and then did kill server worked on linux

Comment: thanks. this resolved the issue. For me, the port 5037 was used up by java. adb commands worked for me once java.exe was terminated from task manager

Answer (score 6):

> Task Manager -> Process -> adb.exe -> End process

That worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but I am using Linux not Windows Pc

Comment: Hi, true the answer is for Windows, I think for Linux you can find the process id of adb and use kill command...hope it helps

Comment: it wont work.. as when u are connected with the device it will automatically restarts the adb server again. so it is useless

Comment: If you are using ubuntu you can go to System Monitor and kill ADB Process

Answer (score 2):

1. navigate to adb.exe folder
2. shift + right click inside the folder
3. start commandline from here
4. unplug any android device connected to your PC
5. type "adb.exe wait-for-device"; press Enter
6. connect your device; wait for commandline to finish
7. done

Answer (score 2):

`adb kill-server` did not work on my Linux computer

First, I used `ps -ef | grep adb` and killed all `adb` deamons`which did not solve the problem.
Then I used`ps -ef | grep java`and saw a process that was blocking the`adb`.

Upon killing that process,  `adb` worked perfectly.
Maybe this process can be helpful for someone.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

On trying to kill multiple adb.exe processes from windows Task Mgr it said "Access is denied". On Windows 7, Resource Monitor allows those adb.exe processes to be killed.

Answer (score 1):

install following packages

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32z1-dev lib32stdc++6
```

if you are using Genymotion then set path of Android SDK in its settings.

ref :http://www.intellicode.in/adb-not-responding-wait-more-or-kill-adb-or-restart/

Answer (score 1):

Install again ADB.EXE in your SDK path like 
**Steps :**

1)Close Your Android Studio

2)Fine path in Your Computer->[drive][your SDK path]\Sdk\platform-tools

3)Replace this path at adb.exe File or Download again if not updated adb.exe File.

4)Click on adb.exe if the command prompt is open and details see and then close automatically then its work. OR if any error occurred or not start adb-server again replace this file .

5)Now successfully run your adb-server open android studio and connect your device after Developer Option ON .

Answer (score 0):

If using the "kill-server" parameter doesn't work you will have to kill the process itself.

In case you use GNU/Linux you have to use the command "ps aux|grep adb" to find the pid of the adb proccess, or directly with "pidof adb" and then "kill PID" where PID is the pid number of the adb process. This should also work with Macintosh and other Unixes (although the parameters of the "ps" command may be different)

In Windows just open the task manager to and kill the adb entry in the proccesses table

Answer (score 0):

From [James Tan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2857193/james-tan)'s answer:

> After investigating for a long time, finally i found out that adb
> daemon keep restarting. and it is because my chrome have enabled
> android debugger. In chrome address bar, open:
> `chrome://inspect#devices`, then uncheck `Discover usb devices`.

Next:

1. Open Power Shell as administrator
2. `cd C:\Users\PC01\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools`
3. `./adb kill-server`
4. `./adb start-server`