# ADB Not Responding - Wait More or Kill adb or Restart (Ubuntu 13) 64-bit

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, adb

I did serious searching both on Google and SO before asking this question - mainly because none of the suggestions out there didn't fix my problem!

After unsuccessfully attempting to make my new Intellij and Android SDK to work on my newly installed Ubuntu 13.10, I am coming to you for help. I know there are thousands of suggestions out there already but none of them worked for me.

Here is what I have tried:

- **adb kill-server**
- **adb start-server**
- **adb devices**

That last command listed my device - and that meant that it was able to detect it without any  issues.

- I have added all the necessary rules like **51-android.rules** and those should be fine.
- Started and restarted the IDE several times without any success.
- I have installed libraries to fix any 64-bit issues
- I even deleted the adb key in the .android folder since it gets generated automatically each time anyway.
- I have no other older versions of IntelliJ or SDKs;
- This was a clean installation of Ubuntu; I totally removed my Windows 8 (yeah, am done with Windows) and installed Ubuntu 13.

I don't know what else to try and do because I have spent hours online trying suggestions from others to no avail.

Any help would be really appreciated because I can't wait to get back to my Android App Development!
Thank you.

**EDIT - SOLUTION**

I solved this problem and then documented it here for others who are having this issue; 
[ADB not responding - the solution](http://simpledeveloper.com/adb-not-responding-android-solution/)

I hope this helps.

Comment: adb kill-server not responding? http://stackoverflow.com/q/8790421/1012284

Comment: I have read that and didn't solve my problem either.

Comment: What *specifically* is not responding?

Comment: When I run the project in my intellij, I get the popup saying : adb not responding. gives options to either "wait more", kill adb, or restart

Comment: You should learn about using adb from the command line, and then you will be able to get a more fine-grained idea of what is wrong.

Comment: That is the only place I use adb (I have used it for a long time on a different machine)

Comment: I finally fixed this problem!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This worked for me (Ubuntu 14.04):

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32z1-dev lib32stdc++6
```

Comment: This was a spot on for me. Thanks.

Comment: This resolved the issue for me on Ubuntu 14.10 64bit. I could run adb from the terminal without problem, restarting adb had no effect.

Comment: Unable to read package.

Answer (score 12):

Close Android Studio
Kill all processess using 5037 port

```
sudo lsof -i |grep 5037

sudo kill PID_NUMBER
```

Run adb devices from console

```
adb devices
```

Comment: this was solve my problem, thanks

Comment: This worked for me but I have to repeat this every time I restart my computer.

Answer (score 3):

I did following

chmod u+x /path/to/adb

and restarted android studio

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. After starting a virtual device I tried to run the app I'm creating, again the error appeared but with a tip added: Install the SDK Platform-tools.
Opened the SDK Manager and realize that the "Android SDK Platform-tools" Rev. 19.0.2 was not installed.
Installed it and ADB started to work without errors.

(I am running Android Studio 6.0 in Ubuntu 14.04 and don't remember removing the Platform-tools)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I'll try to help you explaining my problem. I was trying to run a Selenium test on my HTC and so have to install an Android Debug Bridge just like you. I believe you don't have problems with installing the bridge. When you connect your device in USB port, try to script "adb devices" and you can see if your device is connected or not. Then I'm not so sure but I think you have to install a server as it was in Selenium Android to stream your data to your phone.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a case of missing dependency, you can solve the problem by installing ia32-libs, lib32ncurses5-dev, and lib32stdc++6 packages using apt-get utility.
This is required in order to run 32 bit apps on 64 bit machine. If the problem persists, then it may also be a case that another client-server programs like lampp is running... It is because android debug bridge is also a client-server program... In this case, what you can do is, stop the program and restart  android studio. You can even try restarting your system...

Answer (score 0):

Be sure the /bin/adb exists and then delete the adb from the Sdk tools, in my case:

```
rm ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb
```

Copy the adb from bin folder into Sdk folder:

```
cp /bin/adb ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure adb is in your user's **$PATH** variable.

or

You can try to locate it with **whereis** and run it with **./adb**

Go to the path **Android/Sdk/platform-tools/** and run this command from terminal

**./adb start-server**