# ADB not responding. If you'd like to retry, then please manually kill "adb.exe" and click 'Restart'

Tags: android

I am a newbie and want to learn android. However, I face difficulties during installation of android studio.

I have installed android studio correctly but when I want to run a Hello World in my android device, it shows

> ADB not responding. If you'd like to retry, then please manually kill
>   "adb.exe" and click 'Restart'

I have searched it from the Internet but it still cannot solve the problem, what can I do to solve it?

Comment: open task manager and look for adb and end its process, and i use eclipse so i do not rilli know for studio, but goto your ddms side goto device then i look for a down arrow icon then i reset it..

Comment: I cannot find adb process in task manager.

Answer (score 21):

I've found the answer to this. This had been plaguing me for days, but so happy to have this fixed.

When I go to task manager the process adb.exe was constantly restarting itself. This is what was causing the issue (for me).

Go to Tools -> Android -> Enable ADB entegration. Untick this. Make sure its status appears as unticked. Now go to task manager and killed the process adb.exe, it will not restart itself this time. Now click run, hey presto, ADB runs. Whoop de doo.

Comment: This is not working for me. Anyone else like me? Have any other solution?

Comment: How do I fix for Mac?

Answer (score 10):

Here is what worked for me on Ubuntu:
I simply removed the file /tmp/adb.log

```
sudo rm /tmp/adb.log
```

Hope it helped.
Cheers.

Comment: It worked for me also thanks alot !! I wasted my 2 hours in that issue.

Comment: whole afternoon on it. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You should first try stopping adb and then restarting it.

Use this command:

```
adb kill-server
```

followed by:

```
adb start-server
```

On Mac OSX: If the adb process needs to be killed, you can use *ps* to show all processes with the following command, (pipe through *grep* to find it easier)

```
ps aux | grep adb
```

You can kill it with the following command, using the process id of adb from the previous *ps* command.

```
kill -9 <process id>
```

Comment: Open a Terminal window (under Applications/Utilities in Mac OSX)

Comment: It states "adb" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: @kman0606 that means adb is not in your path or (somehow) you haven't installed the android sdk

Comment: @bumbobway when I type the command "ps aux" how am I to identify adb in the list that shows up? I searched the list for adb but it doesn't show up in the list and the error persists.

Comment: @CanIHaveSomeChange Then how can I install the android SDK? Indeed, I download the package from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#

Comment: @CanIHaveSomeChange if adb is not in your process list, it is already dead. Close Eclipse and call adb start-server.

Comment: @kman0606 what's your OS? Windows? you're using Android Studio?

Comment: @bumbobway I am running Android Studio on Ubuntu. I typed the command "adb kill-server" but when I go to run the project I get the same erorr.

Comment: @CanIHaveSomeChange I am not familiar with Ubuntu, but I found a similar question that might solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22381790/adb-not-responding-wait-more-or-kill-adb-or-restart-ubuntu-13-64-bit

Comment: @CanIHaveSomeChange I am using 64bits Window 7 and using Android Studio. What should I do right now?

Comment: @kman0606 I haven't installed it on W7 so all I can do is go off of what I see on this page http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=studio. If you did the install under the link "download Android Studio now" I would assume it should just work, if not try following the instructions on the link titled "stand-alone SDK Tools install." But before you do this I would go to computer>properties>environment variables>path and at the end of the text box line add a semicolon then paste in the path to where your adb file is located;more info here https://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519

Comment: @bombobway Thanks, I tried everything in that post before. (and I just did again to double check) and nothing worked. I even followed the link in the post to the outside website. Still nothing.

Answer (score 5):

you need platform-tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip . Url for it from google's repository is:

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip

Go into your android-sdk-linux directory, I deleted the platform-tools directory (but I think that's unnecessary) and unzip'ed the platform-tools zip there.  The SDK updater correctly shows 23.0.1 is installed at this point.

all will work properly

one can find detailed discussion  about this issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=ubuntu&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&groupby=&sort=-id&id=196866)

Comment: If it works for you, you should up vote  the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I had the problem because the project was not built and showed an error as follows

Error:Error: Cannot run program "/path/to/Android/Sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory

I solved the problem by running those commands

sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
sudo apt-get install lib32z1

Ubuntu can't run the aapt on 64 bit before installing this packages

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/27734148/2119981

Comment: how to install this package on arch linux

Comment: says the package is not available.

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem.Open cmd and input `netstat -aon|findstr 5037`  .if there is a process uses the port.You should kill it.You can get the pid and find the process in Task Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I Battled with this problem for a couple of days (nearly drove me nuts) and every solution I found failed to help me. Till I tried this:

(On Mac)

I uninstalled Android Studio (moved it from Applications to Trash).

Restarted my Mac.

Reinstalled Android Studio (moved it back from Trash to Applications).

And everything was back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find adb.exe in the task manager so i did the following and it worked fine after that

1. I closed the emulator and removed my phone.
2. restart the windows.
3. connect the usb device and then i run the application.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools -> Android -> Enable ADB entegration
 untick it and press run ( you will get an error) now re-tick it and press run and it will works.

Answer (score 0):

Open "Android Monitor" window at the bottom of Android Studio, there will be some error info of the problem.

And my problem hint is "no permission to access /tmp/adb.1001.log".

Just remove the file, the problem will been resolved.