# Android Studio - ADB not responding. If you'd like to retry, then please manually kill "adb" and click 'Restart'

Tags: android, android-studio

So I've wanted to run a basic app I just made and then this message popped up.

ADB not responding. If you'd like to retry, then please manually kill "`adb`" and click '`Restart`'

I did try a couple of fixes I could find but nothing worked so far, any help is greatly appreciated.

I am running **Linux 15.10 32BIT**

Edit:
Everything I tried:

**1)**

Use this command:

```
adb kill-server
```

followed by:

```
adb start-server
```

**2)** Go to *Tools -> Android -> Enable ADB entegration*. **Untick** this. Make sure its status appears as unticked. Now go to task manager and killed the process adb.exe

**3)** Also reinstalled `Android Studio` and `Java SDK`

Comment: Could you please tell us what you have tried? and have you tried what the error message says?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ADB not responding. If you'd like to retry, then please manually kill "adb.exe" and click 'Restart'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652628/adb-not-responding-if-youd-like-to-retry-then-please-manually-kill-adb-exe)

Comment: Updated my post with everything I tried

Answer (score -1):

C:\Users\sdk\platform-tools
files are missing in the platform-tools.
Complete the missing files will be resolved(It must be like the second image)

[image]

[enter image description here][2]