# Android studio..i got an error while running the hello world on android studio 6 can you please solve it

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

ADB not responding. If you'd like to retry, then please manually kill "adb.exe" and click 'Restart
            what to do now to resolve this error

Comment: Please clarify your question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27652766/5722385

Comment: Manually kill "adb.exe" and click "Restart"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can try the following to get ADB working:

- First search for adb.exe in processes of **task manager** and end it and try to run application.

If the above doesn't work or you can't see adb.exe in task manger go for the next way

- Open command prompt, give path of **platform-tools** and write following commands one after other

  1. adb kill-server
  2. adb start-server