# ADB not responding. If you'd like to retry, then please manually kill “adb” and click 'Restart'

Tags: android, android-studio, 32-bit, linux-mint

So... this problem made me banging my head against the wall for about two day now. When I try to run my android project the error mentioned on the title field appears on pop-up window. I am using android studio on 32bit Linux-mint distribution. I've tried the bellow solutions but, none has solved the issue.

1. [Go to Tools -> Android -> Enable ADB entegration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652628/adb-not-responding-if-youd-like-to-retry-then-please-manually-kill-adb-exe)

   #### My results:

   `adb kill-server
    adb start-server`

   `adb devices`
    `daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037`

   `daemon started successfully
    List of devices attached
    . 
    .`
    
    No devices is listed
2. [Install dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22381790/adb-not-responding-wait-more-or-kill-adb-or-restart-ubuntu-13-64-bit)

   #### My results:

   `Reading state information... Done
   E: Unable to locate package lib32z1
   E: Unable to locate package lib32z1-dev
   E: Unable to locate package lib32stdc++6
   E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'lib32stdc++6'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to execute adb in Ubuntu. Downloaded file is meant for x86-64 while I have i686](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283851/unable-to-execute-adb-in-ubuntu-downloaded-file-is-meant-for-x86-64-while-i-hav)

Answer (score 5):

This is SOLVED now! Downgrading the platform-tools version did the trick.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/714653/adb-android-studio-ubuntu-error-unable-to-detect-adb-version-adb-output-hom

Thanks man! If I could, I would give you a big hug right now.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the adb from the package manager: (at least on ubuntu but mint is derrived from ubuntu so it should work there too)

sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb

then use the normal terminal: adb shell

and this might seem obvious, but enable usb debugging on your phone.

Comment: I have adb tools already installed and emulator configured. The error is saying adb not responding. Not adb not found.