# Maximum number of devices connected to an ADB server

Tags: android, adb

According to [Android Debug Bridge](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html) :

> The server then sets up connections to all running emulator/device
> instances.  It locates emulator/device instances by scanning
> odd-numbered ports in the range 5555 to 5585, the range used by
> emulators/devices.  Where the server finds an adb daemon, it sets up a
> connection to that port.  Note that each emulator/device instance
> acquires a pair of sequential ports — an even-numbered port for
> console connections and an odd-numbered port for adb connections.  For
> example:
>
> Emulator 1, console: 5554
>
> Emulator 1, adb: 5555
>
> Emulator 2, console: 5556
>
> Emulator 2, adb: 5557 ...

The ADB server only checks for devices by scanning odd-numbered ports in the range 5555 to 5585 ( 30 ports in total) and assigns 2 ports for each device. Is ADB capable of accepting more than 15 Android Devices (15x2 ports) or can I connect more devices on the same computer? I think it is impossible to run more than one ADB servers on the same machine.

Comment: If  adb service runs at port 5037 then why does it locate devices in the range 5555 to 5585 ?

Comment: because it needs a persistent connection for every device, thus a port for every device

Comment: can you please give me some examples of adb clients and what adb clients really are. I used to think that the devices that I connect to my machine i.e phone/emulator are clients but instead they are adb devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run more than one instance of adb on the same computer using the environment variable `ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_PORT`. see more details on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10865020/1135732).

With the -ports option on the emulator, you can specify any port, and then do:

```
$ adb connect localhost:PORT
```

If your phone is rooted you can restart adbd on another port (see [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3623727/1135732)), and then:

```
$ adb connect IP_OF_DEVICE:PORT
```

The device is then available over wifi and does not need to be plugged in.
**Be aware that anyone on your wifi network can access your phone this way!**

Comment: Is it possible to access a not rooted device over wifi?

Comment: No, the device must be rooted, and you must change the settings from a root prompt on the device, or `adb shell` must give you a root prompt (my phone usually does not, though it has `su` installed). I don't know how to get back to USB when `adb shell` does not give a root prompt, short of rebooting.

Comment: Yes, you can do ADB over wifi with non-rooted devices.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp

Answer (score 7):

Max number of ports used by adb can be changed by setting `ADB_LOCAL_TRANSPORT_MAX_PORT` environment variable. You can simply [take a look](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/modules/adb/client/transport_local.cpp;l=52?q=ADB_LOCAL_TRANSPORT_MAX_PORT&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject) on the adb code (it's opensource because it's part of Android). You can see that max number of adb ports is set like this:

```
static int adb_local_transport_max_port = DEFAULT_ADB_LOCAL_TRANSPORT_PORT + 16 * 2 - 1;
```

where `DEFAULT_ADB_LOCAL_TRANSPORT_PORT` is 5555. Each device requires 2 ports (console connection + adb connection). So use this formula to calculate your max port: `max_port = 5555 + 2 * N + 1`

Read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/machine-learning/oml4r/1.5.1/oread/creating-and-modifying-environment-variables-on-windows.html#GUID-DD6F9982-60D5-48F6-8270-A27EC53807D0) how to set environment variable on Windows. And for Linux/macOS it can be done by simply editing `.bash_profile` (or `.profile`) file in your home directory. So there's actually no need in additional adb servers like Ashley suggests in another answer.