# Eclipse ADT crashes with no real reason

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a problem with my Eclipse ADT. Everytime I create an Android Application
project, the program crashes with no reason.

I thought that the problem was because of the Eclipse ADT version, so I
downloaded the normal Eclipse and tested it. I have not had problems there so far.
Only at the Eclipse ADT version. I also downloaded the newest Eclipse ADT from developer.android.com, but it changed nothing.

Operating system : Opensuse 13.1

Comment: There should be a log file somewhere.

Comment: See in your home directory for a log file. Also no error is shown? Eclipse simply closes or what happens exactly?

Answer (score 8):

I was having the same problem, I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203771/eclipse-continue-crash). Adding the following line to the end of the eclipse.ini file has so far solved the issue for me:

-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla

Hope that helps!

Jackson

Answer (score 2):

Maybe is adb problem, as I know, adb is use 5073 as default port, sometime it will be occupied by other process.
try `adb shell` to find out does it work fines.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a very common problem, sometimes you cannot do anything, either the `adb` will not respond, or it will **crash**. As you are working on `linux` so, "***`ADB` not responding***" is not so often. `ADB` uses port number **5037**, so probably when you start your Application another instance of the same process gets created trying to access the same `port number`.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836571/changing-default-port-i-e-5037-on-which-adb-server-runs/10865020#10865020),here she has told about changing the default port number. Try  this, may this work.
Well Apart from this, *I would add `ADB` is a burden. It is like a bull, powerful but of his own mood*.

Answer (score 0):

Start eclipse from the terminal, and reproduce the error. Some information will be printed out to the terminal by the jvm when the crash occurs, which may be helpful in diagnosing your problem.