# Eclipse continue crashing

Tags: java, eclipse, webview, crash

today my Eclipse continue crashing and show me this message:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f9d6dfd4c91, pid=5739, tid=140316573566720
#
# JRE version: 7.0_25-b30
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x6ac91]  soup_session_feature_detach+0x11
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /home/panthe/eclipse/core or core.5739
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-7/
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Check bug report https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404776 . I suggest you to upgrade to the newest Eclipse 4.3 (Kepler).

Alternativelly you can try workaround [suggested in comment #6](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404776#c6):

> For a workaround add the following to the end of your eclipse.ini
>
> -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla

Comment: Hi, Pavel. I've used your suggested workaround and now all works fine! Thanks ;-)

Comment: Thanks! This workaround works for Tizen IDE for Wearable SDK v1.0.0b2 Ubuntu 64-bit under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit / Linux Mint 17 64-bit

Comment: Tizen IDE for Wearable SDK bug report: https://bugs.tizen.org/jira/browse/TDIST-663

Comment: Thanks @PavelHoral it works on ZendStudio 10.0 with Linux Mint 16 64bits... Add this to the end of ZendStudio.ini...

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked on Linux Mint 17 64bit Eclipse Juno Java 8

Answer (score 1):

**Upgrade to 4.3 or 4.4 works better**, since for some Eclipse projects it continues to crash (egit, ADT...). If you are running old version of Eclipse I suggest you to delete the old installation and reinstall new version of Eclipse.

Install latest Eclipse in [Ubuntu 14.04](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/install-latest-eclipse-ubuntu-14-04/)