# Aptana closes unexpectedly

Tags: crash, aptana

I just installed Aptana Studio 3.4.2 on a fresh install of Linux Mint 16 with Oracle java. The program closes unexpectedly. So far I've only used it with the Python perspective active.  It seems to happen more often when I'm editing an html file. I used it for 3 hours one day before it crashed; other times only 10 minutes.

The log file has a recurring error that may be related but I can't find any info on it:
!MESSAGE Invalid preference page path: XML Syntax.

Does anyone know what is causing this?

Java Version:

```
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

Aptana Diagnostic:

```
Host OS: Linux
OS Version: 3.11.0-12-generic
OS Arch: x86_64

JRE Version: 1.7.0_45
JRE Vendor: Oracle Corporation
JRE Home: /opt/java/jdk1.7.0_45/jre

Aptana Studio 3 Version: 3.4.2.201308081805
Install Directory: file:/opt/Aptana_Studio_3/
Workspace Directory: file:/home/jeff/workspace/
VM Arguments: -Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-Declipse.p2.unsignedPolicy=allow
-Declipse.log.size.max=10000
-Declipse.log.backup.max=5
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar
/opt/Aptana_Studio_3//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar

Language: en_US

Node.JS Version: Not installed
NPM Path: Not installed

ENV:
MDMSESSION=default
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/run/user/1000/keyring-ka4Jsn
SHLVL=1
SSH_AGENT_PID=1662
TEXTDOMAINDIR=/usr/share/locale/
XFILESEARCHPATH=/usr/dt/app-defaults/%L/Dt
GDM_XSERVER_LOCATION=local
SESSION_MANAGER=local/jeff-main:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1585,unix/jeff-main:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1585
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
CLUTTER_DISABLE_XINPUT=1
GDMSESSION=default
XDG_SESSION_COOKIE=812a644561ed637b3aa6135652bf871c-1389232561.233987-1413464634
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/default:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/usr/share/mdm/
MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/default.mandatory.path
PWD=/home/jeff
GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE=/home/jeff/Desktop/AptanaStudio3.desktop
MDM_XSERVER_LOCATION=local
LOGNAME=jeff
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/keyring-ka4Jsn/gpg:0:1
GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID=3387
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring-ka4Jsn/ssh
NLSPATH=/usr/dt/lib/nls/msg/%L/%N.cat
TEXTDOMAIN=im-config
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-9GHbJcIE3A,guid=4d478335c530a3bf45ec18fb52ce01b1
SHELL=/bin/bash
GNOME_KEYRING_PID=1509
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-default:/etc/xdg
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
DESKTOP_SESSION=default
APTANA_VERSION=3.4.2.1368863613
DISPLAY=:0.0
USER=jeff
HOME=/home/jeff
XAUTHORITY=/home/jeff/.Xauthority
XDG_SEAT=seat0
WINDOWPATH=8
XDG_SESSION_ID=c1
DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/default.default.path
MDM_LANG=en_US.UTF-8
USERNAME=jeff
XDG_VTNR=8
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 3):

I Had the same problem with PHP. I found out that the program terminate when I hover my mouse over an object. So far so good after disabling the hover.

To disable: Window -> Preferences -> Content Assist -> Show information on hover: off

Answer (score 1):

Try add
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
in AptanaStudio3.ini

[Eclipse continue crashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203771/eclipse-continue-crash?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 1):

open `AptanaStudio3.ini` and append this line to end of file:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

Answer (score 0):

Try install Xterm and open again.