# Eclipse w/ADT crashing with "import android." statement in editor

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I'm new to Android Dev and am following developer.android.com/training. I'm at the "starting another activity" section and whenever I try to enter "import android.view.View;" into MainActivity.Java, Eclipse crashes on me. Specifically I can type in "import android" and once I add the period it crashes. Am I missing or need to install additional files? My OS is Linux Mint.

Thanks for your help

Beginning of the error log that was generated:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fb090ea7c91, pid=2473, tid=140399027877632
#
# JRE version: 7.0_25-b30
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x6ac91]  soup_session_feature_detach+0x11
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried looking at the error log more closely and after searching this line:

```
C [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x6ac91]  soup_session_feature_detach+0x11
```

I came across [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203771/eclipse-continue-crash).

Adding the following to my eclipse.ini file fixed the problem, though I am clueless as to how or why...

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't typically type in import statements.  In Eclipse I use the Ctrl + Shift + O shortcut that will bring in all the missing imports.

Do you have your environment variables set, something like

```
setenv PATH /usr/local/jdk1.6.0_15/bin:$PATH
setenv JAVA_HOME /usr/local/jdk1.6.0_15
```

Comment: I didn't have those set up but I added the following to my .bashrc file (I learned about this file just yesterday):

    export PATH=/opt/adt-bundle-linux/sdk/tools:/opt/adt-bundle-linux/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH
    export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/java

Eclipse is still crashing once I enter the period after "import android"

I even tried starting over with a fresh install of Linux Mint 16, JDK7, and the Android SDK. Any other suggestions? I've spent a lot of time trying to figure it out and its getting quite frustrating.