# Eclipse ADT Bundle crashes suddenly on Mint 16 Petra

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, linux-mint

I recently installed Linux Mint 16 Petra (Cinnamon 64 bit) on my laptop (Quad core, 8 GB ram).

I downloaded ADT Bundle for Linux (64 bit). As I start to use Eclipse for coding in Android, I notice that Eclipse suddenly crashes. I don't get any log error, it just crashes. It's happening frequently.

Why does it crash?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a solution right here on stackoverflow.

[Eclipse continue crashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203771/eclipse-continue-crash)

For a workaround add the following to the end of your eclipse.ini

-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla