# Eclipse crash and close every time opened

Tags: java, eclipse

I faced an fetal error with eclipse ide, when i try to open eclipse load GUI and then close, that occur each time opened eclipse ide.

```
Error Loading DDMS Preferences
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f5a0c9822a1, pid=4316, tid=140027354994432
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_45-b18) (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.45-b08 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x6c2a1]  soup_session_feature_detach+0x11
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /opt/eclipse/hs_err_pid4316.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug
```

**Work around**

- change eclipse owwner.
- run eclipse as root.
- Extract jdk again on /opt.
- Made link to jre from /opt to /usr/bin.

**But problem still exists, any help will be appreciated.**

Comment: what is PermGen Memory for eclipse ?

Comment: @unknown 512M `-Xms40m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203771/eclipse-continue-crash) my problem had been solved.

```
For a workaround add the following to the end of your eclipse.ini

-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

Answer (score 0):

If

`-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla`

doesn't work and your OS is debian, try solution in this post:

http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=115477