# ADT keeps crashing all the time

Tags: android, sdk, adt

I have problem in launching the adb or running my application my ADT keeps crashing or keeps not responding i already tried some ADB KILL-SERVER,ADB START-SERVER but it's not working i also tried to put the full path of platform tools in the environment variables but no lucks.I also tried to manual kill the adb.exe in task manager and restart my ADT but still it will hang or keeps not responding.I am using windows 7 32bit.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update your Android SDK tools with SDK manager. Make sure that no other process is running on port 5037. ADB runs on port 5037 by default.

Post the error messages that you get when you launch adb from command prompt.

Comment: Hi,is it possible to change the default adb port to other port,if ever some application uses 5037?

Comment: Yeah. Please check my answer here [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836571/changing-default-port-i-e-5037-on-which-adb-server-runs/24238475#24238475)

Comment: But I am not sure on how to configure eclipse to start adb server on a specific port. Above comment is to start adb server on any port from command line.