# Change ADB Port

Tags: android, adb

I want change ADB port which run on default port on 5037. I want to change this port because my port on 5037 is used by program Baidu ADB Component (Baidu Android Store from Baidu PC Faster using same port 5037).

I have tried to kill that process but access denied. Please see my image [here](http://s4.postimg.org/csbivl0vx/image.png):

I know someone have posted similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836571/changing-default-port-i-e-5037-on-which-adb-server-runs), but its not helping me.

I have tried :

`1. Open CMD as admisitrator and type :`

```
-netstat -ano |findstr "5037"
```

which generate PID of application that using port 5037, then

```
taskkill /pid PORT /f /t
```

then said `access denied`

`2. following this` [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24238475/1533670) `from stackoverflow but generate :`

```
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5555 *
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error: cannot connect to daemon
```

`3. Have tried using program process explorer from` [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)

and tried to kill Baidu ADB component but generate some result `access denied`

`4. Trying to stop service but it said cannot be completed`

So, I think this problem can solve by change ADB port. I don't want to uninstall Baidu PC faster or Baidu Android Store. Any idea? how to perform this?

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

command to run adb server on different port
`adb -P 12345 start-server`

adb server starts on 12345 port

Comment: Note that the order is important -- the -P flag doesn't work if it's not before the command

Answer (score 1):

export ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_PORT=5036