# Configuring Android Studio to run adb server on different port

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

[image: Android Studio retrying "adb.exe start-server" indefinitely]

Hi, is there any way I can configure Android Studio to use different port when running adb?

(e.g. I want it to run `adb.exe -P 5038 start-server` instead of the default `adb.exe start-server`)

I've looked through Android Studio settings but couldn't find any settings to change the port.

I know I can run the command from cmd, but it gets tedious when I have to run it every time I want to use my emulator. Also, port 5037 is used by another (necessary) process, so I can't kill said process.

Any kind of help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70090358) `ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_PORT` env variable is used by adb/android studio on linux.

I have just added the following line to the beginning of `studio.sh` as a hacky but quick solution:

```
export ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_PORT=<port number to use>
```