# How to change ADB port on OS X

Tags: android, macos

"adb,start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary".
This error information show on Android Studio.
I have try to input sudo lsof -i tcp:5037 on Terminal, but nothing has shown.
And I have tried kill adb on Activity Monitor, it still not working.
I can change ADB port on Win7, just create a environment variable, named ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_PORT.

How to create a similar variable in OS X?

If my description not clear, tell me, please.

Comment: what happens when you execute 'adb devices' in terminal?

Comment: * daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *

Comment: Are you seeing any devices? Try to connect a device and then run 'adb devices' again. if that works - open android studio and see if you can debug

Comment: No devices, but my devices 'mx5' is connected use USB.

Comment: Let's take this to [stackoverflow chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118123/shai-jay)

Comment: You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here.... ^-^ Sorry..

Comment: You need to make sure that: a) your device has USB debugging enabled b) once connected to the computer, you must authorize the connection on the device, it's like a small popup that is displayed on the device when you initially connect it to the computer

Comment: Yes, debugging is enabled. Authorize selected in yesterday. The adb working well in yesterday. I'm trying use android asist software make sure my device connected correctly. I only a little English. Thank your commit very much. But I can't adopt a commit as a anwser. May you anwser the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing default port (i.e. 5037) on which adb server runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836571/changing-default-port-i-e-5037-on-which-adb-server-runs)