# ADB Failed To Start Daemon

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-virtual-device

I've been having this trouble in my adb for two days, when i start android studio i got this error,

```
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
could not read ok from ADB Server
* failed to start daemon
error: cannot connect to daemon
'D:\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
```

What i have tried to troubleshoot this error :

```
1. Disable Firewall
2. Add adb.exe to allowed apps in firewall
3. run adb devices as administrator
4. run adb kill-server as administrator produce this error `cannot connect to daemon at tcp:5037: cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:5037: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)`
5. adb start-server as administrator
6. Restart my laptop
7. Reinstall platform-tools
8. Reinstall android studio
9. Disable antivirus
10. The port 5037 is not in use
11. I don't have genymotion, only avd
12. The adb.exe is not in Task Manager
13. Install older platform-tools
```

But the problem still persist, anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: I have tried all answer on post above (This question already has answers here post) but it's not working for me.

Comment: in the end i try to change the adb port, following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37369271/9046933